# Date and time box userform VBA combine to one cell

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

I want to use a DTbox to determine date and time. Problem is I can't figure out how to make the one box record both date AND time.   I have 4 boxes total.
`userform1.startdate userform1.starttime userform1.enddate userform1.endtime`.
And I would like to have those subtract from each other to get a difference in hours (if 15+ goes to 1 hour, if less to 0).
 I'm not 100% caring if we use the DTbox if there is a better way to get a user submitted date and time to subtract from each other.
I tried to format a box to be `startbox=format (date, mm/dd/yy hh:mm)` but because that didn't work I deleted startbox to create the dtboxes listed above.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just create a text box and on userform initialize made it so that it reads `userform1.startdate.value=now`. supposing that the user follows that form it works. so its good for a temp solution. also got rid of start and end times